# I have text file. want to add commas to time/date stamp in txt file or convert below text to csv in 3 columns

Tags: awk

I have text file. want to add commas to time/date stamp

```
$ cat sample.txt
 name1 [jdk]                 Mon Nov 01 12:14:04 EST 2004     Mon Jan 01 00:37:19 EST 2035
```

I want output like below and need to convert to `csv` file.

```
name1 [jdk],Mon Nov 01 12:14:04 EST 2004,Mon Jan 01 00:37:19 EST 2035
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed no matter what your white space is and no matter what text comes before the first date:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*\S)\s+((\S+\s+){5}\S+)\s+((\S+\s+){5}\S+)$/\1,\2,\4/' sample.txt
name1 [jdk],Mon Nov 01 12:14:04 EST 2004,Mon Jan 01 00:37:19 EST 2035
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `awk` for this:

```
cut --output-delimiter="," -c1-28,29-56,62- sample.txt | sed -e "s/ *,/,/"
```

`cut` will read fixed-width file and convert it into delimited file

`sed` will remove extra spaces at the end of the fields

Comment: Thank you for quick response/help Ninov/White. But i have number of names like below.
Note: Names are having different lengths of characters. 
 
name********* [jdk] Fri May 29 01:00:39 EDT 2009  Tue May 29 01:00:39 EDT 2019
 name2*********** [jdk] Tue Nov 07 14:31:18 EST 2006  Mon Dec 31 14:40:55 EST 2006
 name3****************[jdk] Fri Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2001  Tue Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2011
 name4*********************** [jdk]Tue Jun 29 13:39:16 EDT 2004  Thu Jun 29 13:39:16 EDT 2014

Comment: So? As long as name does not exceed 28 characters - my sample will work fine. If you have different field widths - recalculate numbers in `-c` key.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]{3,}/,",",$0);print }' file1
```

output

```
name1 [jdk],Mon Nov 01 12:14:04 EST 2004,Mon Jan 01 00:37:19 EST 2035
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use awk because in it you can change the odd date sting to something more usable: the timestamp in seconds after epoch:

```bash
$ awk -F '[ \t:]' 'BEGIN{ m="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" }
               { sub("^"FS,"")
                 mon1 = (match(m,$4)+2)/3;
                 sec1 = mktime($10" "mon1" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8 );
                 mon2 = (match(m,$12)+2)/3;
                 sec2 = mktime($18" "mon2" "$13" "$14" "$15" "$16);
                 print( $1,$2,",",sec1,",",sec2 )
               }
    ' sample.txt

name1 [jdk] , 1099311244 , 2051224639
```

Note that because the second parameter is `1` in mktime, the timestamp is taken to be in UTC time. Change it to 0 if the timestamp is in local time.

Comment: Thank you quartz. Is it convert for only specific date(above date) or will it convert any date to seconds. Can you pls clarify.

Comment: Yes Quartz  I tried. Working in UTC but not working EDT..

Comment: Yes. Getting below error.
awk: cmd. line:4:               sec1 = mktime($10" "mon1" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8 ,1);
awk: cmd. line:4:                                                              ^ 2 is invalid as number of arguments for mktime

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting on more than 1 space?

```
awk -F' {2,}' 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { $1=$1 } END { print }' infile

name1 [jdk],Mon Nov 01 12:14:04 EST 2004,Mon Jan 01 00:37:19 EST 2035
```